# Запрос к XML в mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, запрос

Имеется кострукция вида:

```
<first>
   <id>...</id>
   <object>...</object>
   <settings>
      <setting>...</setting>
      <setting>...</setting>
      <setting>...</setting>
   </settings>
</first>
```

Кол-во элементов `setting` не известно. То есть в каждой записи может присутствовать от 0 до n данных элементов.

Я понимаю, как вывести единичные элменты. Например, `id`:

```
SELECT column.value('(first/id) [1]', 'integer') AS 'id' FROM table
```

Но вот с множественными элементами возникает вопрос.
Требуется чтобы при запросе я получил список вида:

```
id | setting
id | setting
....
```

Comment: какая версия sql-server?

Comment: Стоит sql-server 2017

Comment: вы хотите сделать данные в базы данных в файл XML?

Comment: @delphi У меня имеется таблица, в которой в колонке xml фалы. Мне и надо их распарсить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Test XML

SET @Test = CAST( 
'<first>
   <id>100</id>
   <object>MyObject</object>
   <settings>
      <setting>
            <param1>p1</param1>
            <param2>p2</param2>
      </setting>
      <setting>2</setting>
      <setting>3</setting>
   </settings>
</first>'
AS XML)

SELECT 
t.f.value('(first/id)[1]', 'integer') AS Id,
n.s.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS params,
n.s.value('(./param1)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS param1,
n.s.value('(./param2)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS param2
FROM (SELECT @Test AS f) t
    CROSS APPLY f.nodes('first/settings/setting/.[1]') n(s)
```

**UPD:** Для приведенного примера выбор из таблицы:

```
SELECT 
    t.column.value('(first/id)[1]', 'integer') AS Id,
    nodes.setting.value('.[1]', 'varchar(100)')
    FROM table t
        CROSS APPLY t.column.nodes('first/settings/setting/.[1]') nodes(setting)
```

Comment: f, я так понимаю, XML столбец. а t, n,s тогда что?

Comment: Все это алиасы: таблица t с полем f и таблица n с полем s

Comment: А как правильно тогда составлять запрос, если в `<setting>..</setting>` есть еще несколько полей, например `<param1>..</param1><param2>..</param2>` и я на выходе хочу получить `id | param1 | param2`? Извиняюсь, если совсем глупый вопрос, но не до конца понимаю принцип работы CROSS APPLY

Comment: Исправил ответ с учетом новых обстоятельств, только не знаю как не выводить все значения в params, а только корневые. CROSS APPLY выполняет запрос для каждой внешней записи и присоединяет результат. Конкретно здесь t.column.nodes(...) возвращает три содержимых <setting>, с которыми дальше можно работать как с xml

Comment: Спасибо! Уже и сам догадался)